# How to escape ~ character in jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select an element this way

```
$('#QR~QID345')
```

because the element's id is `QR~QID345` but the selector doesn't work with `~`, is there any fix?

Changing the id is not an option in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can escape `~` with `\\`

```js
alert( $('#QR\\~QID345').text() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="QR~QID345">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$.escapeSelector` to escapes any character that has a special meaning in a CSS selector.

```js
var id = $.escapeSelector("QR~QID345");

console.log($('#' + id).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="QR~QID345">
  Hello World
</p>
```

As been noted by Rory McCrossan on the comment, `$.escapeSelector` was added on version 3.0

Doc: [$.escapeSelector()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/)

Comment: Note that this is only available in jQuery v3+